# Always returns status code 200 from Module.php

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, authorization, http-status-codes

I want to return status code 403 from Module.php whenever authorization fails. I searched and found out that I need to attach listener to this file.

I am trying to do it this way. But I am getting 200 even if I am setting statusCode to 500. 
See the code below.

```
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    // Authorize API call
    $auth =  $this->authorize($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager());

    if(!auth)
    {
            $app = $e->getApplication();

            $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($app) {

                $response = $e->getResponse();
                $response->setStatusCode(500);

                $response->setContent(json_encode(array(
                             'message' => 'You are not authorized for this request',
                 )));

                 return $response;

           }, PHP_INT_MAX);


    }
```

[image: Response from API Call]

Comment: Do you have this code in your `onBootstrap` method, and are you sure the module is enabled in your application.config.php?

Comment: yes this code is in onBootstrap method. and I think if it's disabled then it would not give this message too.

Comment: is your zf2 version in last stable version? the code above give me the  expected results in my application. or maybe some other user component is messing up the response code?!

Comment: Yes some other code was messing with this. I wasn't getting proper response so I re-did code for some of the controllers. It started working. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other controller was causing problem and when I copied and paste some of the code, It started to work..

Thanks @ins0 for this suggestion.